# Finding memory leaks from asan?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and I meet some memory leaks problems seem like they are not from my code. Where are they from? I know they are from somewhere of my code but they are different with all of the form the previous errors. Previous errors would tell where are the leaks in my code, in which file and which line. But this time it doesn't. Please tell me if you know!

I've searched on the web it seems like a leak from asan. But I don't know what it is and how to use it. Can you help me to figure it out and solve it please!

Thank you!!!

Following is the error:

```
=================================================================
==6138==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1683970 byte(s) in 101 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c8e74  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddbe74)

Direct leak of 276667 byte(s) in 62 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674a06 in __interceptor_calloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:153
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c92db  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddc2db)

Direct leak of 896 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674c3e in __interceptor_realloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:163
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c8582  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddb582)

Indirect leak of 590161 byte(s) in 1281 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c8e74  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddbe74)

Indirect leak of 436144 byte(s) in 647 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674a06 in __interceptor_calloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:153
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c92db  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddc2db)

Indirect leak of 1040 byte(s) in 7 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4e1b674c3e in __interceptor_realloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:163
    #1 0x7f4e0c7c8582  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.470.103.01+0xddb582)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 2988878 byte(s) leaked in 2099 allocation(s).
make: *** [/home/***/ics2021/nemu/scripts/native.mk:29: run] Error 1
```

My source code are follow:

```
  #include <common.h>
  #include <device/map.h>
  
  #define SCREEN_W (MUXDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SIZE_800x600, 800, 400))
  #define SCREEN_H (MUXDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SIZE_800x600, 600, 300))
   
    uint8_t* new_space(int size) {
    uint8_t *p = p_space;
    // page aligned;
    size = (size + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)) & ~PAGE_MASK;
    p_space += size;
    assert(p_space - io_space < IO_SPACE_MAX);
    return p;                                                                 
  }

  static uint32_t screen_width() {
    return MUXDEF(CONFIG_TARGET_AM, io_read(AM_GPU_CONFIG).width, SCREEN_W);                                                                            
  }
 
 static uint32_t screen_height() {
    return MUXDEF(CONFIG_TARGET_AM, io_read(AM_GPU_CONFIG).height, SCREEN_H);
  }
  
  static uint32_t screen_size() {
    return screen_width() * screen_height() * sizeof(uint32_t);
  }
  
  static void *vmem = NULL;
  static uint32_t *vgactl_port_base = NULL;
  
  #ifdef CONFIG_VGA_SHOW_SCREEN
  #ifndef CONFIG_TARGET_AM
  #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
  
  static SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
  static SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
  
  static void init_screen() {
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    char title[128];
    sprintf(title, "%s-NEMU", str(__GUEST_ISA__));
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(
        SCREEN_W * (MUXDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SIZE_400x300, 2, 1)),
        SCREEN_H * (MUXDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SIZE_400x300, 2, 1)),
        0, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, title);
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);
  }
  
  static inline void update_screen() {
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, vmem, SCREEN_W * sizeof(uint32_t));
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }
  #else
  static void init_screen() {}
  
  static inline void update_screen() {
    io_write(AM_GPU_FBDRAW, 0, 0, vmem, screen_width(), screen_height(), true);
  }
  #endif
  #endif
  
  void vga_update_screen() {
    // TODO: call `update_screen()` when the sync register is non-zero,
    // then zero out the sync register
  }
  
  void init_vga() {
    vgactl_port_base = (uint32_t *)new_space(8);
    vgactl_port_base[0] = (screen_width() << 16) | screen_height();
  #ifdef CONFIG_HAS_PORT_IO
    add_pio_map ("vgactl", CONFIG_VGA_CTL_PORT, vgactl_port_base, 8, NULL);
  #else
    add_mmio_map("vgactl", CONFIG_VGA_CTL_MMIO, vgactl_port_base, 8, NULL);
  #endif
  
    vmem = new_space(screen_size());
    add_mmio_map("vmem", CONFIG_FB_ADDR, vmem, screen_size(), NULL);
    IFDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SHOW_SCREEN, init_screen());
    IFDEF(CONFIG_VGA_SHOW_SCREEN, memset(vmem, 0, screen_size()));
  }
```

Comment: These leaks aren't from your source code, they are coming from libraries, which is caused because of some problem in *your source code*. So, share your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code contains calls to the functions `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer` and `SDL_CreateTexture`, but I see no calls to the functions [`SDL_DestroyWindow`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture), [`SDL_DestroyRenderer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyRenderer) and [`SDL_DestroyTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture). That is a [resource leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak) in your program, which probably leads to a resource leak inside the SDL library, which leads to a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) inside the Nvidia OpenGL library. Only the latter is detected and reported by LeakSanitizer.

Comment: On modern OS(es) freeing heap memory isn't very needy. But, freeing resource is a very good practice.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Yes, it's especially good to always free resources since you may want to search for memory leaks at some point, like OP now wants to do. Having a ton of memory leaks to go through to find the "real" problem is a pain.